# HOURLY SALES REPORT

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Good morning guys.
I need your help again.
Im doing a sales report but I cant get the output I want.

My code is this:

```
Select Cast(TIME As Varchar(100))+ '-' + CAST(DATEADD( MINUTE, 59, TIME)As varchar(100))  As TIME, SUM (TOTAL) as HOURLY_SALES 
From tblSales
Where Mall = 'Mall1' and ORDATE  = '6/2/2014' and VOID = 'N' 
Group By OTIME
```

and its given me this output:

```
   Time                    HOURLY_SALES 
12:00-Jan  1 1900 12:59PM   295.00
13:00-Jan  1 1900  1:59PM   2122.86
14:00-Jan  1 1900  2:59PM   2230.00
15:00-Jan  1 1900  3:59PM   1800.00
16:00-Jan  1 1900  4:59PM   3090.00
17:00-Jan  1 1900  5:59PM   880.00
18:00-Jan  1 1900  6:59PM   652.86
19:00-Jan  1 1900  7:59PM   1890.00
20:00-Jan  1 1900  8:59PM   2272.86
21:00-Jan  1 1900  9:59PM   520.00
```

I dont know where the date come from.
Please help me to remove the date.

The output shoulbe like this:

```
       Time              HOURLY_SALES

    12:00- 12:59PM  295.00
    13:00-  1:59PM  2122.86
    14:00-  2:59PM  2230.00
    15:00- 3:59PM   1800.00
    16:00-  4:59PM  3090.00
    17:00-  5:59PM  880.00
    18:00-  6:59PM  652.86
    19:00-  7:59PM  1890.00
    20:00- 8:59PM   2272.86
    21:00-  9:59PM  520.00
```

I'm using visual studio 2010 and ms sql server 2008
Hope you'll help me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: The DATETIME in sql server is represented as a floating-point value containing both date and time representing the number of milliseconds from an epoch. One part of the float represents the date and the other part represents the time. It seems that your time column is of type DATETIME.

Comment: what should be my column type? Im sorry, Im a newbie. thanks

Comment: Your column type is not the issue. It looks like the data was stored with MINDATE to indicate null, meaning the date should be ignored or is not used. You probably just need to parse the time pieces out and set the DATE portion to midnight of the current date or midnight-1 second of the previous date (or cast the time portion to a string). I suggest that you look up date and time parsing in sql server...you can find tons of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing this instead?

```
select (cast(datepart(hour, [time]) as varchar(255)) + ':00 -' +
        cast(datepart(hour, [time]) as varchar(255)) + ':59'
       ) as [time],
       SUM (TOTAL) as HOURLY_SALES 
From tblSales
Where Mall = 'Mall1' and ORDATE  = '6/2/2014' and VOID = 'N' 
Group By cast(datepart(hour, [time]) AS VARCHAR(255));
```

Comment: thank you so much. Sir Gordon Linoff and Sir Aaron Bertrand. :) your code give me the right output.